# how to update by join two tables in mysql

Tags: mysql

i have 3 tables

1. iata_en table 3 columns (city_name, country_name, iata_code)
2. d_cities table 3 columns(city_name, country_id, iata_code)
3. d_country table 2 columns (country_id, country_name)

i want to copy iata_code column from table iata_en to d_citites table where (iata_en.cityname=d_cities.cityname)and iata_en.countryname = d_cities.country_name)

- so i joined d_cities and d_country with foreign key to get
  country_name.

*i write this code but it doesn't work*

```
UPDATE d_cities
        SET iata_code=iata_en.iata_code
        FROM iata_en,d_cities as ci 
        INNER JOIN d_country as co
        ON ci.CountryID=co.CountryID
        WHERE iata_en.city_name=ci.city
        AND iata_en.country_name=co.country
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All table references have to be specified in the `UPDATE` clause even if you're not actually updating them.

```
UPDATE
    d_cities
    JOIN d_country USING (CountryID)
    JOIN iata_en ON (
        city_name = city
        AND country_name = country
    )
SET
    d_cities.iata_code = iata_en.iata_code
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
 UPDATE D_CITIES CITIES
JOIN D_COUNTRY COUNTRY ON COUNTRY.COUNTRY_ID = CITIES.COUNTRY_ID
JOIN  IATA_EN IATA ON IATA.CITY_NAME = CITIES.CITY_NAME
SET CITIES.IATA_CODE = IATA.IATA_CODE;
```

Comment: no it is not what i want..i want to sure the country name and the city name equal the city and country name which in iata_en before transfer iata_code..so i want to join d_cities and d_country before copy data